# How can I use recorded audio from web browser as a value in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Currently I'm making web based voice recorder which will upload the recorded audio to the server. Before upload it to server, the user need to record audio & input few fields such as audio name etc.

I'm using RecordJs from MattDiamond https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs. When a user clicks on the stop recording button, an audio player will appear and user can play it. If the user decided to use it, they will click a button to use that audio and it will be an input value to a file type input field. The code is shown as below:

```
var url;

function stopRecording() {
    mediaStream.stop();
    rec.stop();
    rec.exportWAV(function(e) {
        rec.clear();
        //Recorder.forceDownload(e, "test.wav");
        url = Recorder.getAudioUrl(e, "audio.wav");
        document.getElementById("audioPlayer").src = url;
        document.getElementById("audioPlayer").style.display = "";
    });
}

function setInputFile() {
    document.getElementById("filename").value = url;
}
```

So far, I managed to capture the audio and play the recorded audio from my browser but I stuck at next step which is to set the recorded audio as a value to the input field. Using document.getElementById("filename").value = url; give an error. Could please anyone in the forum give any suggestion how to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a form element for input file. For example, in function createDownloadLink() you have to add this lines

```
 var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
      x.setAttribute("type", "file");
```

After that, you have to set input value with blob url you generate in createDownloadLink() function.

```
x.setAttribute("value", url);
```

Then, you have to append the input file tag together with the list tag.

```
li.appendChild(x);
```

The full implementation is as shows below.

```
 function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');
      var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
      x.setAttribute("type", "file");
      x.setAttribute("value", url);

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      li.appendChild(x);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
```